# net config server displays

Tags: windows-8.1, home-networking, smb, netbios

The `net config server` command displays:

```
server name \\DAN-LAPTOP
Software version   Windows 8.1
Server is active on NetbiosSmb <DAN-LAPTOP>

Server hidden    Yes
Maximum Logged on Users: 20
Maximum open files per session: 16,384

Idle Session Time (min):  15
```

Is this normal? I have not setup a server. This is just my personal laptop, connected to the internet.

Comment: You have file sharing enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal.

"Server" here doesn't mean that the computer as a whole is meant to be used as a server. Rather, it means that it *acts as* a server – it lets others connect to it – for some purpose or another. For example, when you set up file sharing on Windows, when someone from another computer browses your files, a program on your computer is accepting the connection and therefore acting as the server for the SMB file-sharing protocol.

And `net config server` is specifically talking about the Windows component that acts as the file sharing server, which is installed by default on all Windows systems, internally called "LanmanServer".

Similarly, `net config wksta` talks about the client side (which connects to file shares on other computers), and `net config browser` is the component that discovers other computers on the network (used to be called "Network Neighbourhood").

---

(In fact, the whole `net` command was originally introduced with LAN Manager, which added the same file sharing functionality to MS-DOS. Only Windows NT made the service management – `net start` and `net stop` – a bit more generic, but all other subcommands still deal with the Windows file sharing.)

Answer (score 2):

#### Is this normal? I have not setup a server.

`NetbiosSmb` is used for **file and printer sharing**.

---

#### File and Printer Sharing Operations

> The file and printer sharing services are provided by the Server Message Block (SMB) protocol. This shall run on top of NetBT session or run directly over TCP. SMB fits well with the client-server topology, where client makes specific requests and the server responds accordingly.
>
> 5.1 Direct hosted SMB
>
> Direct hosted SMB traffic uses port 445. This does not use NetBT. Here, a four-byte header precedes the SMB traffic. The first byte of this header is always 0x00, and the next three bytes are the length of the data.

> This is useful in systems that do not support NetBT and in network
> where NetBT is not preferred.
>
> If the Client has NetBT disabled, it will always try to connect to the server at port 445 only. If the server answers on port 445, the session shall be established and continued on that port. If it doesn't answer, the session will fail completely. When the server has NetBT disabled, it shall listen on port 445 only and respond to requests to this port.
>
> 5.2 SMB over NetBT
>
> If both the direct hosted and NetBT interfaces are enabled, both methods are tried at the same time and the first to respond is used. This allows interoperability with operating systems that do not support direct hosting of SMB traffic or NetBT.

Source [IETF - Server Message Block and NetBIOS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-palanivelan-netbios-smb-04#page-6):

---

#### Microsoft uses SMB over Netbios to implement file and printer sharing.

> **SMB**
>
> - Server Message Block (SMB), aka Common Internet File System (CIFS).
> - **Application layer protocol to network access to files, printer, etc**. as well as inter process communication
> - New version (SMB2) introduced with Windows Vista
> - **Originally used NetBIOS and NetBIOS over TCP/IP for communication.
> - Uses NetBIOS datagram and session service.**
> - Direct communication over 445/TCP added with Win 2000
> - Broadcast traffic issues were due to WINS
> - SMB2 might only support 445/TCP and not NetBIOS, but I don't know.
> - History:
>   Originated at IBM
>   Microsoft merged it with LAN Manager
>   Designed to run over NetBIOS
>
> **NetBIOS**
>
> - ```
>     Provides services related to OSI session layer
>   ```
> - ```
>     NetBIOS is an API, not a networking protocol
>   ```
> - ```
>     Developed in 1983, used for a bunch of things, but now only known as API providing services for SMB.
>   ```
> - ```
>     Older OSes ran NetBIOS over Ethernet, IPX/SPX using NetBIOS Frames (NBF)
>   ```
> - ```
>     Now mostly NetBIOS over TCP/IP (NBT). (NetBIOS is now used as synonym for NBT)
>   ```
> - ```
>     Nodes have a NetBIOS name and an IP address.
>   ```
> - NetBIOS over TCP/IP services.
>   Standardized in
>   RFC 1001
>   RFC 1002
>   Provides: + Name Service (Port 137/UDP) + Datagram Service (Port 138/UDP) + Session Service (Port 139/TCP)
> - **SMB runs on top of NetBIOS**

Source [Microsoft SMB, SMB2, NetBIOS, WINS protocol suite](http://www.icir.org/gregor/tools/ms-smb-protocols.html):

Comment: Very thorough and useful answer, thanks! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`Server` does not refer to you actually hosting a server, but at the "Server" service, that supports things like file and print sharing.

So yes, it is normal.

Turning it off will result in impossibility of sharing files and printer on the network.